# How am I using vector iterators incorrectly?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

This code works:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i != m_cResources.getLoadedPlayers().size(); i++) {
    m_cResources.getLoadedPlayers()[i]->update();
}
```

When I try to use iterators with the following code, my programs hangs and stops working:

```
for (std::vector<CPlayer*>::iterator i = m_cResources.getLoadedPlayers().begin();
        i != m_cResources.getLoadedPlayers().end(); i++) {
    (*i)->update();
}
```

getLoadedPlayers() returns the vector of CPlayer*. Update is a member function in CPlayer.

I've never used iterators before so I'm not really sure what is wrong. I don't think the error is outside of this code because the first block works. So I assume my implementation of the iterator is wrong. Any ideas?

EDIT: getLoadedPlayers() returns the vector by value, not reference. Would this most likely be the problem? But then wouldn't the first code block also not work? I will test this as soon as I can.

The update function modifies member values in a CPlayer based on flags previously set.

Comment: Does anything in `CPlayer::update` modify the vector returned by `getLoadedPlayers()` (and thus might invalidate the iterator)?

Comment: And style note:  prefer `++i` for iterators to `i++`.

Comment: Does `getLoadedPlayers` return the vector by reference, or by value?

Comment: @JoeZ: Not just style, also an efficiency concern.

Comment: @EduardoLeón : True enough.

Comment: @VJC1288: Could you give us the signature for the member function `getLoadedPlayers`?

Comment: Have you tried running it under a debugger, or adding a print statement inside of the update method?

Comment: If possible, just use a range-based `for` loop: `for (auto i :  m_cResources.getLoadedPlayers()) i->update();`

Comment: getLoadedPlayers() returns the vector by value. Should it return by reference? I thought that since the values in the vectors were pointers to the original CPlayers that it wouldn't matter.

Comment: @EduardoLeón and @JoeZ: Why is `++i` more efficient than `i++`?

Comment: @VJC1288: `++i` merely increments `i` and returns just that. `i++` first creates a temporary value (the old value of `i`) so that, after incrementing `i`, the temporary value can be returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If as you said getLoadedPlayers() returns the vector by value, not reference then the first loop also has no sense because in each iteration a new copy of the vector is used in expression

```
m_cResources.getLoadedPlayers()[i]->update();
```

When you use iterators in the loop

```
for (std::vector<CPlayer*>::iterator i = m_cResources.getLoadedPlayers().begin();
        i != .getLoadedPlayerm_cResourcess().end(); i++)
```

then iterator i and getLoadedPlayerm_cResourcess().end() point to differenent memory extent. So they may not be compared.

If you want that your loops had any sense you should use reference to the original vector.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use C++'s for each?

```
for (auto &i : m_cResources.getLoadedPlayers()) {
  i->update();
}
```

Comment: If the problem is return by value, and if update() is meant to produce a lasting effect in the object, then the above won't solve The Real Problem.

Comment: Nice suggestion. Little nitpicking: the vector's elements are themselves pointers, so it should be `i->update();`.

Comment: Of course, it does require C++11 support, which unfortunately isn't everywhere yet.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf That is why reference `&i` is used. And even then, it is not necessary since those are pointers. So the method `update` would be executed  on original objects anyways.

Comment: @luk32: no, we're talking about `getLoadedPlayers()` returning its result by value. doesn't help to update a temporary object.

Comment: @luk32: i think you didn't understand (the response isn't meaningful). think about it. ;-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: But it's a vector of pointers, and he's calling a function through the pointers dereferenced, so it should work fine.  Granted, it would be better if the function returned the vector by reference.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: you're most likely right, be we don't know that. Oh sorry, you're right. Mea culpa! Coffee...

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: It can be inferred from the problem description (the vector is a vector of pointers), but admittedly it is a sneaky little detail that is easy to overlook.

Answer (score 1):

Your vector is returned by value, so your iterator which is incremented each iteration of the loop will never "meet" the end iterator in the loop exit condition : it belongs to another vector (changed at each iteration).
So your code invokes undefined behavior by dereferencing an invalid iterator (and the underlying pointer)